# How to skip TestNG test based on Selenium OS running the test

Tags: selenium, testng

I would like to be able to skip tests based on the OS running the test. To be clear this is not the OS running the actual tests,

I've done this before using IInvokedMethodListener throwing SkipExceptions for other product specific things but thought this was common enough there might be something already out there instead of creating my own?

JUnit5 has @EnabledIfSystemProperty that would work but I'm tied to use only TestNG. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up basically implementing the annotation on my test platform.